# Passing JSON as props - Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm making a JSON request, which returns a JSON object. I would like to handover the data to a component function for display purposes, but when I do, it's giving me the error:

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I've summarised it below and the full code including the function is also attached.

---

JSON:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2...c3ca2d4736dcfe

I'm storing all the above in state, then I'm passing it as props:

```
<WeatherCard data={this.state.weatherdata} />
```

I can then log the props in the function and I get:

```
Code:
 {cod: "200", message: 0.0081, cnt: 5, list: Array(5), city: {…}}
  city: {id: 2643743, name: "London", coord: {…}, country: "GB", population: 1000000}
  cnt: 5
  cod: "200"
  list: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  message: 0.0081
  __proto__: Object
```

I can log props.data.city as well:

```
Code:
  {id: 2643743, name: "London", coord: {…}, country: "GB", population: 1000000}
  coord: {lat: 51.5085, lon: -0.1258}
  country: "GB"
  id: 2643743
  name: "London"
  population: 1000000
  __proto__: Object
```

So you'd think I'd be able to do **props.data.city.name** to get the city name, but no. I get Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import WeatherCard from './components/WeatherCard'

const config = {
  API: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,uk&units=metric&cnt=5&APPID=",
  API_KEY: process.env.REACT_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY
}

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      weatherdata: "",
      isLoaded: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(config.API + config.API_KEY)
      .then( result => result.json() )
      .then ( 
        (result) => {
          this.setState({ 
            weatherdata: result,
            isLoaded: true
          })
      },
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: false,
          error: error
        })
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <WeatherCard data={this.state.weatherdata} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;


------

import React from 'react';

function WeatherCard(props) {
  console.log(props.data.city.name) <---- this fails
  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default WeatherCard
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API has probably not returned the results before you are trying to access it. Try `console.log(props);` and you'll notice that `props` would be empty the first time.

You should render the `WeatherCard` component only when `isLoaded` is set to `true`.

Something like:

```
    {this.state.isLoaded && (<WeatherCard data={this.state.weatherdata} />)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to API is asynchronous, and you are trying to render your `WeatherCard` component before receiving results from API.

Use your `isLoaded` state variable to render the component only when you have data.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {this.state.isLoaded && (<WeatherCard data={this.state.weatherdata} />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Cheers! Worked a treat :)

Answer (score 0):

Your component render before fetch gave it's result, so do just like this.
 set in initial state

```
weatherdata: {},
```

- weatherdata should be object, for your case.

Then, in fetch response set not whole response, but only data you need

```
 this.setState({ 
            weatherdata: result.city,
            isLoaded: true
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the props to a state in componentWillMount ans then use it inside your components

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your data has been loaded or not.. and then render your stateless component.

```js
// Example stateless functional component
const SFC = props => (
  <div>{props.label}</div>
);

// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      weatherdata: "",
      isLoaded: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22')
      .then( result => result.json() )
      .then ( 
        (result) => {
          this.setState({ 
            weatherdata: result,
            isLoaded: false
          })
      },
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: false,
          error: error
        })
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       {this.state.isLoaded? <h1>Loading...</h1> :  <WeatherCard data={this.state.weatherdata} />}
        </div>
    );
  }
}


function WeatherCard(props) {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
    This is weather Data
    </div>
  )
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```